# Efficient row-wise operations on a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rowwise

I need to find the row-wise minimum of many (+60) relatively large `data.frame` (~ 250,000 x 3) (or I can equivalently work on an `xts`).

```
set.seed(1000)
my.df <- sample(1:5, 250000*3, replace=TRUE)
dim(my.df) <- c(250000,3)
my.df <- as.data.frame(my.df)
names(my.df) <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

The data frame `my.df` looks like this

```
> head(my.df)

  A B C
1 2 5 2
2 4 5 5
3 1 5 3
4 4 4 3
5 3 5 5
6 1 5 3
```

I tried

```
require(data.table)
my.dt <- as.data.table(my.df)

my.dt[, row.min:=0]  # without this: "Attempt to add new column(s) and set subset of rows at the same time"
system.time(
  for (i in 1:dim(my.dt)[1]) my.dt[i, row.min:= min(A, B, C)]
)
```

On my system this takes ~400 seconds. It works, but I am not confident it is the best way to use `data.table`.
Am I using `data.table` correctly? Is there a more efficient
way to do simple row-wise opertations?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Or, just `pmin`.

```
my.dt <- as.data.table(my.df)
system.time(my.dt[,row.min:=pmin(A,B,C)])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.02    0.00    0.01 
head(my.dt)
#      A B C row.min
# [1,] 2 5 2       2
# [2,] 4 5 5       4
# [3,] 1 5 3       1
# [4,] 4 4 3       3
# [5,] 3 5 5       3
# [6,] 1 5 3       1
```

Comment: Sorry if this is hijacking, but if I am dynamically creating the list of columns, e.g. any column that is a POSIXct type, or whose name matches an expression, giving me a variable such as: x=c("A","B","C") ... how do I use "x" in the pmin expression? It is using the literal values of x rather than scoping them out to the values in the columns.

Comment: @gkaupas That would make a good question. Wild untested stab: `DT[,do.call(pmin,.SD),.SDcols=x]` or perhaps `do.call(pmin,lapply(x,get))`. The first way using `.SDcols` should be more efficient. You don't have to group to use `.SD`. You can add a `by` clause as well if you need to, without changing `j`.

Comment: Thank you Matthew. The first worked, and I needed to add na.rm=TRUE to it, which took a little trial-and-error, but I ended up with `DT <- DT[,NEWCOLNAME:=do.call(pmin, c(.SD, na.rm=TRUE)), .SDcols=x]`. I was wondering where `.SDcols` was documented and found it in the [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) for release 1.6.3, but not in any of the help() topics.

Comment: @gkaupas Great. I just checked `?data.table` and `.SDcols` is documented there (search the help page for "SDcols").

Comment: Apologies, of all the obvious places to look, that was the one I didn't check. I was trying things like ??.SDcols and even just ??SD and not getting any relevant hits.

Comment: @gkaupas  No problem at all. I'm not sure what `??` does, but if there is a way to search all a package's documentation (all help files & vignettes) for a particular string, then I'd like to know, too!

Comment: `help("??")` directs to `help.search()` which will search documentation "matching a given character string in the (file) name, alias, title, concept or keyword entries"... i.e. not the entire help text. Presumably `.SDcols` isn't in the concept or keywords, so it doesn't show up. The rules for searching a vignette are: "The 'name' and 'alias' are both the base of the vignette filename, and the 'concept' entries are taken from the \VignetteKeywords entries. Vignettes are not classified using the help system "keyword" classifications."

Answer (score 27):

After some discussion around [row-wise first/last occurrences from column series in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008486/row-wise-first-last-occurrences-from-column-series-in-data-table), which suggested that melting first would be faster than a row-wise calculation, I decided to benchmark:

- `pmin` (Matt Dowle's answer above), below as **tm1**
- `apply` (Andrie's answer above), below as **tm2**
- melting first, then min by group, below as **tm3**

so:

```
library(microbenchmark); library(data.table)
set.seed(1000)
b <- data.table(m=integer(), n=integer(), tm1 = numeric(), tm2 = numeric(), tm3 = numeric())

for (m in c(2.5,100)*1e5){

  for (n in c(3,50)){
    my.df <- sample(1:5, m*n, replace=TRUE)
    dim(my.df) <- c(m,n)    
    my.df <- as.data.frame(my.df)
    names(my.df) <- c(LETTERS,letters)[1:n]   
    my.dt <- as.data.table(my.df)

    tm1 <- mean(microbenchmark(my.dt[, foo := do.call(pmin, .SD)], times=30L)$time)/1e6
    my.dt <- as.data.table(my.df)
    tm2 <- mean(microbenchmark(apply(my.dt, 1, min), times=30L)$time)/1e6
    my.dt <- as.data.table(my.df)sv
    tm3 <- mean(microbenchmark(
                melt(my.dt[, id:=1:nrow(my.dt)], id.vars='id')[, min(value), by=id], 
                times=30L
               )$time)/1e6
    b <- rbind(b, data.table(m, n, tm1, tm2, tm3) ) 
  }
}
```

(I ran out of time to try more combinations) gives us:

```
b
#          m  n        tm1       tm2         tm3
# 1: 2.5e+05  3   16.20598  1000.345    39.36171
# 2: 2.5e+05 50  166.60470  1452.239   588.49519
# 3: 1.0e+07  3  662.60692 31122.386  1668.83134
# 4: 1.0e+07 50 6594.63368 50915.079 17098.96169
c <- melt(b, id.vars=c('m','n'))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(c, aes(x=m, linetype=as.factor(n), col=variable, y=value)) + geom_line() +
  ylab('Runtime (millisec)') + xlab('# of rows') +  
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(title='Number of columns'))
```

[image]

Although I knew `apply` (tm2) would scale poorly, I am surprised that `pmin` (tm1) scales so well if R is not really designed for row-wise operations.  I couldn't identify a case where `pmin` shouldn't be used over melt-min-by-group (tm3).

Comment: You don't need to create `id` here, you could just do `melt(my.dt, measure.vars = names(my.dt))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg `melt(my.dt, measure.vars = names(my.dt))` returns a data.table with two columns, `variable` (A,B,C) and `value`.  Without `id` I don't know how to group by the original row number (of the unmelted data.table).

Comment: 3 years later, this is still the best answer to this question in general.  I wish I could upvote multiple times.

Answer (score 24):

The classical way of doing row-wise operations in R is to use `apply`:

```
apply(my.df, 1, min)
> head(my.df)
  A B C min
1 2 5 4   2
2 4 3 1   1
3 1 1 5   1
4 4 1 5   1
5 3 3 4   3
6 1 1 1   1
```

On my machine, this operation takes about 0.25 of a second.

Comment: Filed under: "try the easy stuff first".

Comment: This converts my.df implicitly to a matrix... generally not a good idea.