# Row wise matrix operations in R

Tags: r, data.table, rowwise

Recently I ran into the `data.table` package.
I'm still not sure how to do row-wise matrix operations.
Was it originally intended to handle such operations?
For example, what would be data.table equivalent to `apply(M,1,fun)`?

`fun` should take a vector as argument, for example `mean`, `median`, or `mad`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the `:=` operator (see `?':='`). A short example and a comparison with the `mapply` function is below (I hope I apply the `mapply` function correctly; I'm only using data.tables nowadays, so no promise on that; but still, the data.table way is fast and in my opinion easy to memorize):

```
library(data.table)
> df <-     data.frame(ID = 1:1e6,
+                     B  = rnorm(1e6),
+                     C  = rnorm(1e6))
> system.time(x <- mapply(foo, df$B, df$C))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.32    0.04    4.38 
> DT <- as.data.table(df)
> system.time(DT[, D := foo(B, C)])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02 
> all.equal(x, DT[, D])
[1] TRUE
```

After posting my answer, I'm not so sure anymore if this is what you are looking for. I hope it does, just give more details if it doesn't (for instance, do you have many columns you want to apply a function to, not just the two in my example?). Anyways, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885147/efficient-row-wise-operations-on-a-data-table) could be of interest for you.

Comment: tmp <- DT[, D := sum(B, C)];  

tmp[1:2, ]  

gives the total sum over all elements. Does not work with mean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885147/efficient-row-wise-operations-on-a-data-table does not generalize to any function (mean).

Comment: @danas.zuokas: Good points. In those cases I guess you would just use the `row...` functions, e.g. `rowSums(DT[, list(B, C)])`, but I think it's best to leave the question open.

Comment: @Danas Or just `apply(DT,1,mad)` as you do normally. That should work. We try and avoid row ops though and prefer column ops, for speed. For example, if along the columns are group names, we tend to put those groups as a key column instead (i.e. _flat_ a.k.a. _tall_ format) and do `DT[,mad(variable),by=group]`. When you need _wide_ format for regressions, you can _reshape_ then (or the data is already wide from some preliminary aggregation step). Like a database.

Comment: Thank you all for your tips. It seems that for very basic operations like row mean rowMeans is most appropriate for tall matrices. For example I use rowMeans((data-centerM)^2) style to compute variance.

Comment: Yes, and the "bare-bones .colSums(),.rowSums(),.colMeans() and .rowMeans() for use in programming where ultimate speed is required" added in R 2.15.0