# row-wise first/last occurrences from column series in data.table

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, rowwise

As a follow-up to this oldie but goodie: [efficient row-wise operations on a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885147/efficient-row-wise-operations-on-a-data-table)

I have some data that (unfortunately) look like:

```
library('data.table')
set.seed(1234)
m <- 5
n <- 7
rb <- function() runif(m,1000,2000) * rbinom(m,1,0.5)   
series_col_nms <- paste0('YearNo',1:n)    
rev <- data.table(cust_id = paste0('CustNo',1:m), 
                other_stuff = sample(letters,m, replace=TRUE))
for(col in series_col_nms){
  set(rev, j=col, value=rb())
}
setkey(rev, cust_id)
```

One row per customer with various columns including yearly revenue for year 1, 2, ...

I would like to get the year indices for the first and last years with any revenue from each customer.

I can produce the desired result, but with a somewhat hacky join:

```
years_active <- rev[, which(.SD>0), .SDcols = series_col_nms, 
                    keyby=cust_id][, .(min_year_active = min(V1),
                                       max_year_active = max(V1)), keyby=cust_id]
years_active[rev]
```

These attempts to get the minimum index fail:

```
rev[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x) min(which(x>0))), .SDcols=series_col_nms, by=cust_id] # returns data type error    
rev[, do.call(pmin, lapply(.SD, function(x) which(x>0))), .SDcols=series_col_nms, by=cust_id] # returns empty
```

What is the `data.table` way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to operate on many columns by row, the common practice it to `melt` your data set first and then operate on a single column.

In your case, a relatively straightforward solution could be something like

```
res <- melt(rev, id = 1:2)[, 
         as.list({
            temp <- value != 0
            if (any(temp)) range(which(temp)) else rep(NA_integer_, 2)
         }), 
        by = cust_id]

rev[, c("Min", "Max") := res[, .(V1, V2)]]
rev
#    cust_id other_stuff  YearNo1 YearNo2  YearNo3  YearNo4  YearNo5  YearNo6  YearNo7 Min Max
# 1: CustNo1           c 1640.311       0    0.000 1759.671    0.000 1503.933    0.000   1   6
# 2: CustNo2           q 1009.496       0    0.000 1201.248    0.000    0.000 1308.095   1   7
# 3: CustNo3           p    0.000       0    0.000    0.000 1484.991    0.000    0.000   5   5
# 4: CustNo4           q 1666.084       0 1831.345 1992.150 1243.929    0.000 1051.647   1   7
# 5: CustNo5           w    0.000       0    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000  NA  NA
```

---

A cleaner version but with warnings could be

```
melt(rev, id = 1:2)[, as.list(as.integer(range(which(value != 0)))), by = cust_id]
```

Comment: I wouldn't call *with warning* version a cleaner one, but dirty one ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Reshaping** I would store the data in long format:

```
mrev = melt(rev, 
  id=c("cust_id","other_stuff"), 
  variable.name="YearNo", 
  value.name="revenue")[revenue > 0]
```

You lose customer 5 with the `revenue > 0` condition, but I doubt that matters.

Then collect aggregate statistics as needed:

```
mrev[ , list(first = YearNo[1], last = YearNo[.N]), by=cust_id]

#    cust_id   first    last
# 1: CustNo1 YearNo1 YearNo6
# 2: CustNo2 YearNo1 YearNo7
# 3: CustNo4 YearNo1 YearNo7
# 4: CustNo3 YearNo5 YearNo5
```

Parsing out the numbers from the strings you've been using is simple, of course.

---

**max.col** I think this is a bad kludge but...

```
max.col(rev[,!c("cust_id","other_stuff"),with=FALSE] > 0, "first")
max.col(rev[,!c("cust_id","other_stuff"),with=FALSE] > 0, "last")
```

You'd have to go back and fill in the special case of all zeros (customer 5) separately.

Comment: Thanks Frank and @DavidArenburg -- this pretty much confirms my original approach, although maybe explicit melting is faster -- do you see any way to use row-wise operations (`pmin`, `.SD`, etc.) for this?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I think that if speed is a concern you should just stick to melted/long data, which data.table is better with. (This also helps you avoid awkwardly putting data into column names.) `pmin` happens to be a hack available for the question linked, but I wouldn't bet on such shortcuts generally being available.

Comment: Thanks (and +1) -- if I could figure out a row-wise solution I would have benchmarked it, but good to know I am on the right track.  I am going to accept @DavidArenburg's solution for his idea with `range()` (otherwise it's a tie)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 rowwise solutions generally bad idea in R unless fully vectorized, simply because R wasn't designed to operate on rows rather on vectors. `melt` is the natural transformation from operating on rows to operating on vectors. `data.table` devs developed `melt` to be fully optimized so this transformation will be seeming-less even for huge data sets.

Comment: @DavidArenburg -- after doing a little [testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885147/efficient-row-wise-operations-on-a-data-table/34019591#34019591) it looks like `pmin` is actually pretty fast.  Let me know if I missed something.  Cheers--

Comment: `pmin` is vectorized and thus isn't doing by row operations. Please reread my comment. In your case there was no a straightforward `pmin` solution that we could identify, thus row-wise operations such as `apply(df, 1,...)` would be the worst solution possible. Also, `pmin` is specific to finding a minimum and that's all. By using `melt` first, you can aply *any* function afterwords, thus this is a general solution compared to a specific hack.

Comment: Btw, if you a Haldey fan, you may want to read [this](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) too.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I second David's recommendation of reading hadley on "tidy data". The idea is not that melting is the fastest way to create this particular pair of columns; it is that working with melted data will make your subsequent operations (which presumably go beyond just making a single column) faster, in both runtime and coding (since you won't have to dig up clever tricks/hacks for each one). The first sentence of my answer is to be taken literally: I would create `mrev` and `rm(rev)`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks.  I just signed up for DataCamp; hopefully after completing the `data.table` course there I will post more informed questions